# Incorrect output from a method

Tags: java

I am writing classes that generate a Parked car, a parking meter, a police officer, and a parking ticket.  They are demonstrated by a program which instantiates them all and puts them to use.  I have 99% of the programming done, but I am coming across a problem within my ParkingTicket class.  Within the class is a method to calculate the fine an owner would pay for their car based on the amount of unpaid time the car was there. The base fine is 25.00 for the first hour or part of an hour the car was illegally parked, and an additional 10.00 per hour or part of an hour after that.
Here is my code for the class:

```
public class ParkingTicket{
  private ParkedCar car;
  private PoliceOfficer officer;
  private double fine;
  private int minutes;
  double BASE_FINE = 25.0;
  double HOURLY_FINE = 10.0;

  public ParkingTicket(ParkedCar aCar, PoliceOfficer anOfficer, int min){
        this.car = new ParkedCar(aCar);
        this.officer = new PoliceOfficer(anOfficer);
        this.minutes = min;

  }

  public ParkingTicket(ParkingTicket ticket2){
     this.car = ticket2.car;
     this.officer = ticket2.officer;
     this.fine = ticket2.fine;
     this.minutes = ticket2.minutes;
  }

    public void calculateFine(){
        int minOver = car.getMinutesParked() - minutes;
        int extraFine = HOURLY_FINE * (minOver / 60);
        if(minOver <= 60){
            fine = BASE_FINE;
        }
        else{
            fine = BASE_FINE + extraFine;
        }
    }

    public ParkedCar getCar(){
        return car;
    }

    public PoliceOfficer getOfficer(){
        return officer;
    }

    public int getMinutes(){
        return minutes;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return "Car Data:\n" + car +
                "\nOfficer Data:\n" + officer + 
                "\nMinutes Illegally Parked: " + (car.getMinutesParked() - minutes) +
                "\nFine: $" + fine;

    }



}
```

The problem I am having is that when the fine is printed, its always 00.00.  I can't seem to figure out why this is.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What are the values for your `fine`, `extraFine` and `minOver` variables inside of your `calculateFine`? My assumption is to look closely there.

Comment: Where do you call `calculateFine`?

Comment: I have checked those. They are also called by the demonstrator program to be displayed, and are displayed correctly. I haven't put in values yet that would give me a negative number, or within the paid time, so I shouldn't be getting zero for the fine amount.

Comment: It isn't currently called, shouldn't it determine the fine without being called?

Comment: That's a new one on me. How can a method be called without being called?

Comment: If it's not called, why in the world would you expect it to be called?

Comment: Sorry, I thought I had seen a method work without being called somewhere.  I'm relatively new to this, so I apologize that.

Answer (score 1):

You're doing int division -- you're dividing an int by an int which will result in an int. Don't do this and make one of the numbers double either by declaring them to be double or by casting the numerator or denominator to be double.

i.e.,

```
double extraFine = HOURLY_FINE * (minOver / 60.0); // note the 60.0
```

Comment: @ChrisW91: but still you must call the method. No method can mathemagically call itself.

Comment: `HOURLY_FINE` is defined as a `double`. Did I missed an edit somewhere?

Comment: Would I be able to call the calculateFine() method within the toString() method somehow?

Comment: @ChrisW91: you could call that method wherever it was needed.